# How to check connection bettween client computer and NAS device

Tags: mount, nfs, nas

I am using Computer Ubuntu 18.04, and i mount folder `/vms-data` with shared folder on the Synology device (NAS, IP = `10.0.0.161`).

```
sudo mount  -t nfs 10.0.0.161:/volume1/VMS /vms-data
```

And the result after call `df -h` command:

```
10.0.0.161:/volume1/VMS  5.3T  4.2T  1.1T  81% /vms-data
```

It seem great, but it have a problem when the connection to NAS is disconnected, and the app which save file to `/vms-data` will be hang. If disconnection time is enough large, the app will be crash.

How do I monitor this NAS on Ubuntu?